# moment - Display different format based on condition

Tags: javascript, date, format, momentjs

I'm using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) and need to display date in the following way:

***If recent (within last 7 days):***

```
Tuesday 9:40am
```

***If not recent (7 or more days ago):***

```
Jun 15
```

It looks like a common use case to me, but I wasn't able to find docs for it. How can I accomplish this? Preferably without additional JavaScript logic.

Answer (score -1):

Use their [`isBetween`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) method.

Check out my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bohdxb0u/1/).

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I was hoping there was a `moment` format solution. Thanks for the fiddle.

Comment: No problem @PetrGazarov. Was the format method from `moment` not what you were looking for (used in my fiddle)?

Comment: No, I was looking to use moment to format this without having to write if - else statement in js code.